# Java-Spring Query DSL

Tags: pom.xml

Getting Compilation error on POM.XML as below:
You need to run build with JDK or have tools.jar on the classpath.If this occures during eclipse build make sure you run eclipse under JDK as well (com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:
 1.1.3:process:default:generate-sources) org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: You need to run build with JDK or have tools.jar on the classpath.If this occures during eclipse build make sure 
 you run eclipse under JDK as well at com.mysema.maven.apt.AbstractProcessorMojo.execute(AbstractProcessorMojo.java:362) at

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
 <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.3</version>
 <executions>
  <execution>
  <goals>
  <goal>process</goal>
   </goals>
  <configuration>
   <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
  <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
   </configuration>
   </execution>
    </executions>
<plugin>
</plugins>
    </build>
 </project>
```

Comment: Set JDK as installed JRE as below:

Comment: SET JRE HOME AS C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101 and also modified eclipse .ini entries file also